# Adding specific text to a random image array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 6 different images in it that randomizes every time the page loads. However I want to display specific text for each image when it loads.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var random_images_array = ["../img/distraction pictures/11aabtk.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/blue-clouds-day-fluffy-53594.jpeg", "../img/distraction pictures/cambridge-66714.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pandas.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pexels-photo-24781.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pexels-photo-28051.jpg"];


    function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
        path = path || 'img/';
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
        var img = imgAr[ num ];
        var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
        document.write(imgStr); document.close();
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep another array and just get the values from that too.

```
 var random_images_array = ["../img/distraction pictures/11aabtk.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/blue-clouds-day-fluffy-53594.jpeg", "../img/distraction pictures/cambridge-66714.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pandas.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pexels-photo-24781.jpg", "../img/distraction pictures/pexels-photo-28051.jpg"];

 var random_texts_array = ["text1", "text6"]; //add others ..


    function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
        path = path || 'img/';
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
        var img = imgAr[ num ];
        var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
        document.write(imgStr);
        document.write(random_texts_array[num]);
        document.close();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution but nothing worked, no images showed up either.

Comment: @andrea did you add all the 6 texts in this array ? `var random_texts_array = ["text1", "text6"]; //add others ..` and then are there any errors in console ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way to go but the easiest would be to create a second array for the text...since you're generating the random number num...that index can be used for both arrays and will pull the image and its corresponding text